# Reaction between lead acetate and carbon dioxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

As we know, $\ce{CO2}$ will not react with $\ce{Pb(CH3COO)2}$ but if I start electrolyzing lead acetate solution and during the process add $\ce{CO2}$ to the solution will $\ce{CO3^2-}$ reacts with $\ce{Pb^2+}$? Can it be a method to synthesise of lead carbonate?

Comment: Why would it? Electrolysis adds nothing to the picture.

Comment: Why do you want to make two different operations simultaneously, namely electrolysis AND adding CO2 ? Why ?

Comment: by using electrolysis I want to replace Pb2+ ions that react with (CO3)2- sth like a circulated situation because I don't want to use lead acetate more and more. is it possible?